# define distance in a manifold over the reals

Tags: metric-spaces, manifolds, differential-topology

G is a Hausdorff manifold over the reals with a finite atlas: $\exists m$ $G=\bigcup_{1 \leq i \leq n}U_i$, $g_i:U_i \to g_i(U_i) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$. 
Can I somehow define a metric inside G, using the metric on each $g_i(U_i)$s (the standard metric from the reals)?
I tried defining some metric which for elements $x,y$ in two different $U_i$s makes $d(x,y) = inf_{t \in U_i \cap U_j} d_i(x,t) + d_j(t,y)$ where for $x,y \in U_i$ we set $d_i(x,y) = |g_i(x) - g_i(y)|$, but I can't manage to get the exact right definition which makes it a metric.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with [Riemannian Manifolds](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannianManifold.html)?

Comment: Not familiar. I guess it can have something to do with it, but in any case I am looking for an explicit formulation of the metric function

Comment: Since you want an explicit metric, the best you can get, I think, is an explicit non-Riemanian distance function on $M$ constructed via an embedding $M\to R^N$ ($N$ is something like $mn$) using a partition of unity subordinate to your atlas.